# Can `tar --list -v` list file size in human-readable format?

Tags: tar, size

I want to list members of `tar` files verbosely, and show the file size in human-readable format not in bytes, does the `tar` has the option to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no built-in `tar` option, but you can filter its output. For example, using [humanize](https://github.com/jmoiron/humanize):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import fileinput
import humanize

for line in fileinput.input():
    (perm, owner, size, date, time, filename) = tuple(line.split())
    print '{0} {1} {2:>9} {3} {4} {5}'.format(perm, owner, humanize.naturalsize(size, gnu=True), date, time, filename)
```

Save this as *e.g.* `humantvf`, then

```
tar tvf ... | ./humantvf
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `awk` together with [`numfmt`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/numfmt-invocation.html):

```
tar --list --verbose --file myfiles.tar.gz | \
    awk '{ \
        "numfmt --to=iec-i --format=%7.f --suffix=B " $3 | getline x; \
        $3=x; \
        print $0 \
    }'
```

This modifies the third column (i.e. the file size column), replacing the number of bytes with a human readable size obtained from `numfmt`.

Result:

```
-rw-r--r-- user/user   16KiB 2020-01-01 12:34 pics/camel.jpg
-rw-r--r-- user/user    2KiB 2019-12-01 12:34 pics/cat.jpg
-rw-r--r-- user/user  410KiB 2019-12-01 12:34 pics/panda.jpg
-rw-r--r-- user/user    2KiB 2019-12-01 12:34 pics/unicorn.gif
# ...
```

Note that `numfmt` is specific to GNU coreutils. It has been available since GNU coreutils 8.21 (released at the beginning of 2013).

Comment: Inspired by @Flux, with GNU coreutils 8.30, perhaps we can just use `numfmt`, like `tar -zvtf myfiles.tar.gz | numfmt --field=3 --to=iec-i --suffix=B`, to handle invalid fields, just appending the option `--invalid=ignore`.

Comment: I can confirm this did work for me as a oneliner with no awk, `tar tvzf file.tar | numfmt --field=5 --to=si`  The program passed through the other fields. And even better news, it was already present in my minimal cygwin.

Answer (score 3):

The solution for making this human readable AND sorting by size was given by @Quar and @Peter. This only prints out the file and size, however you can add more by adding to the `print` statement in `awk` - for example this adds the file name as well:

```
tar -tvf $1 \
  | numfmt --field=3 --to=iec-i --suffix=B \
  | awk -v size="$size" '$3 >= size {print $3" "$6}' \
  | sort -hr \
```