# How to measure size of piped data?

Tags: pipe

I would like to do something like this:

```
> grep pattern file.txt | size -h
16.4 MB
```

or something equivalent to:

```
> grep pattern file.txt > grepped.txt
> ls -h grepped.txt
16.4 MB
> rm grepped.txt
```

(that would be a bit inconvenient, though)

Is that possible?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use `wc` for this:

```
grep pattern file.txt | wc -c
```

will count the number of bytes in the output. You can post-process that [to convert large values to “human-readable” format](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/327031/86440).

You can also use [`pv`](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) to get this information inside a pipe:

```
grep pattern file.txt | pv -b > output.txt
```

(this displays the number of bytes processed, in human-readable format).

Comment: I prefer `wc -c` because `du -h` returns ` 4.0 K` if it is any smaller than 4,0k as it reads in blocks

Comment: If printing the output in MB is enough, the command could be `| wc -c | sed 's/$/\/1024\/1024/' | bc`. This appends `/1024/1024` to the output and runs a calculator on the resulting string.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the pipeviewer tool [`pv`](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/quickref/pv.shtml) with the total byte count flag `-b`:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero bs=3 count=4211 2>/dev/null | pv -b >/dev/null
12.3KiB

$ grep pattern file.txt | pv -b >/dev/null
```

Answer (score 4):

The [Pipe Viewer](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) utility was designed for this purpose.  If it's not flexible enough for your purposes, then you can implement your own FIFO data transfer measuring code with the pipeline manipulation library ([libpipeline](http://libpipeline.nongnu.org/)) function calls such as `pipeline_pump()` and `pipeline_peek_size()`.

```
$ whatis pv
pv (1)               - monitor the progress of data through a pipe
$ pv -Wi 0.002 -cf /etc/hosts | wc -l
 367 B 0:00:00 [2.71MiB/s] 
[============================================================================>] 
100%
10
$
```

Comment: used it like this $raspivid -n -o - -t 0 |  pv -Wi 0.002 > /dev/null

Answer (score 1):

One could quickly brew their own solution in Python:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

count = 0
while True:
    byte = sys.stdin.read(1)
    if not byte:
        break
    count =  count + 1

print(count)
```

Works as so:

```
$ echo "Hi" | ./count_stdin_bytes.py
3
$ echo "Hello" | ./count_stdin_bytes.py
6
$ dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=1024 2>/dev/null |  ./count_stdin_bytes.py 
1024
```

---

Since in your particular case you're dealing with text data ( judging from the fact that you pipe from `grep`),  you could also make use of `bash`'s `read`. Something like this:

```
$ echo "Hello" | { while read -n 1 char; do ((count++)) ;done ; echo $count; }
6
```

Comment: Why is this better than `wc -c`? `while read ...` will probably be significantly slower. Also, OP asked for human readable output as in  (`ls -h`)